# Deleting a post from Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to delete a post from Jekyll, I tried removing the markdown file from github and copying new .md file to the _posts folder and commit. But it is not updating on the blog and previous post still remains there.

Comment: In your github repository **settings**, check if you have a build error in the **github pages** frame.

Comment: @DavidJacquel . Thanks a lot. There was some build error only. Now it's resolved.

Comment: @Shashank Please post the answer yourself and set it to resolved... :-) That is how this system works.

Answer (score 0):

As David Jacquel answered as a comment:

In your GitHub repository settings, check if you have a build error in the GitHub pages frame.

(posting here just to be easy to find an answer in a future.)